# Filling the space with tabs with icons TabLayout

Tags: android, tabs

I'm currently using TabLayout to use sliding Tabs in my app and I'm facing a Problem: The Tabs are using Icons and they aren't filling up the whole space. I googled it and searched much on SO but no solution worked for me. I'm compiling with SDK 23 btw.

Current Code in MainActivity.java:

```
final TabLayout slidingTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
    // Center the tabs in the layout
    //slidingTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    slidingTabLayout.addTab(slidingTabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.btn_tabs_feed));
    slidingTabLayout.addTab(slidingTabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.btn_tabs_friends));
    slidingTabLayout.addTab(slidingTabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.btn_tabs_messages));
    slidingTabLayout.addTab(slidingTabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.btn_tabs_notifications));
```

layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMode="scrollable"
    style="@style/CustomTabLayout"/>
```

CustomTabLayout:

```
<style name="CustomTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabIndicatorColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="tabGravity">fill</item>
    <item name="tabMaxWidth">0dp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself, it was to make the tabs fixed and not scrollable.